# Document Type images are broken

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I'm new to Sharepoint 2010; when adding a web part for users to download files, the 'Type' images are always broken, and the URLs have no image file. For example:

[image]

Then when looking at the path of the broken image, it comes up as:

```
https://portal.mysite.com/_layouts/images/
```

Is there some sort of association I have to make?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some digging, I noticed in my DOCICON file had some invalid XML in it; specifically some of the pdf mapping.

After removing the invalid characters, and restarting IIS, the document icons have now appeared.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Content Editor web part then you have to Add the icon (DocIcon) of the file-type to a custom xsl-template.

Please see below given link

> http://freedotnet4u.blogspot.in/2013/01/add-icon-docicon-of-file-type-to-custom.html

Thanks